# VS Code - Dynamically link IntelliSense to files from Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, vscode-extensions

Im looking to add IntelliSense support to my VS Code Extension.
Within the extension i have a few files like:

```
server.d.ts
client.d.ts
```

And files like below, with the d.ts that should provide IntelliSense behind it.

```
/server/script.js > server.d.ts
/client/script.js > client.d.ts
/widget/script.js > server.d.ts
/widget/widget.js > client.d.ts
```

I have the data for the mapping, but cant figure out what to do in the extension. Clues?

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try this extension,

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=christian-kohler.path-intellisense